# Receive data from mysql in node.js to draw graph

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, node.js

I'm learning node.js and i want to write a program that draws a graph of data fetched from mysql database. I am doing the back end processing in the server.js file and showing results in index.html. Since i'm new to node.js and web programming. I don't know how to get data as a javascript object and draw it's graph.

Question:
I want to know how would i send the data fetched into the javascript object to the graph drawing code.

Here is my server.js :

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require('express');
var app =express();
var country = [], population = [], gdp = [];
var jsonArray;

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: '12345',
  database: 'rohan'
});
var queryString = 'SELECT * FROM Country';

// Fetching data from database
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  connection.query(queryString, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if(err) throw err;
    formatData(rows);
    res.send(jsonArray);
    console.log(jsonArray);
  });
});

function formatData(dataArray) {
  for(var i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
    country[i] = dataArray[i].name;
    population[i] = dataArray[i].population;
    gdp[i] = dataArray[i].GDP;
  }
  jsonArray = [country, population, gdp];
  console.log("in FormatData()...\n");
  console.log(jsonArray);
}

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server listening on port 3000");
});
```

and this is my index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Chart-mysql demo</title>
    <script>
      // code to draw graph
      $("#clients").bind('ajax:success', function(result) {
        console.log("In index.html" +  result);
        alert(result);
        var barData = {
          label:result.country,
          datasets: [
            {
              label: '2010 Customers #',
              fillColor: '#382765',
              populationData:result.population
            }
          ]
        };
       var context = document.getElementById('clients').getContext('2d');
       var clientsChart = new Chart(context).Bar(barData);

      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Country Demographics</h1>
    <script src="Chart.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <canvas id="clients" width=500 height=400></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So you are already getting receiving the data on the client and question is about how to draw it?

Comment: No, i'm not receiving data on client.

Comment: I am receiving data, but i want data as a javascript object so that i can use it to get processed by chat.js

Comment: Have you tried turning node.js off and on again?

Comment: Kidding. We're missing information here, you should probably post the contents of `app.js` as well.

Comment: Actually it's my mistake...I forgot to remove the line containing app.js. there is no app.js. I moved content to app.js to index.html in <script> tags.

Comment: Well, there's code parts clearly missing there that'd be relevant for us to be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of head scratching i finally did it.As far as server side was concerned i was doing it right. I just didn't know how to deal with data on the client.  To receive data as a javascript object, I added a button and connected an AJAX call to it's onclick() event.

```
  <body>
    <h1>Country Demographics</h1>
    <button id="Get_Graph" onclick="gData(); return false">Get Graph<button/>
    <canvas id="clients" width=500 height=400></canvas>
  </body>
```

And to handle it's click event, here is javascript code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Chart.js"></script>

<script>
  // code to draw graph

  function gData() {
    $.get("http://localhost:3000", function(result, status) {
      alert(result);
      var barData = {
        labels:result[0],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: '2010 Customers #',
            fillColor: '#382765',
            data: result[2]
          }
        ]
      };
     var context = document.getElementById('clients').getContext('2d');
     var clientsChart = new Chart(context).Bar(barData);
    });
 }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first write a module which would fetch the data(you have got a piece of code which connects to the database so we can skip this part).

Then we should write a router which would pass the data to the pathname (when it is called) for example like this:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    api.apiGet(function (data){
```

> -> importing data from module (api is a variable importing the module, apiGet a function from api).

```
        res.render('portal', {result: data}); -> data is passed as result
    });
});
```

Then you would write a view which would use that data, for example in Jade it would be the following.

```
{val[4].label}
```

It just grabs the data which is send in JSON.

If you need something clearing just write :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i am not using views. I just want to send the mysql SELECTED data as an javascript object to client side code. I would really appreciate if you could provide some  more code to handle index.html file.

Answer (score 0):

As I see you haven't get data from node.js app. First of all you need to somehow retrieve this html from server, so you need to add something like:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.html');
});
```

Then you need to change your current app.get('/' to some another url. Let's say "/data".
After that change you need to change your current index.html, and add there JS code, which will request data from "/data". You can use jquery for that. Take a look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ Then you will get an JS object in callback of Jquery ajax request to node.js "/data".

Comment: Hmmm, I'm sending the data from the app.get(..) { } method. I am receiving it on client side but the problem is i want to receive it in a javascript object. Yeah, an AJAX call  can make this possible. I would really appreciate if you could tell me the JQUERY event that would be triggerred when the url would be changed.

Comment: I'm sorry, but not sure what do you mean under "url chanded". You mean that you have opened html file, and then navigate with browser to new url?

Comment: To make ajax call on page load you can just move your function gData content outside of function.